# Scan and scroll query not working when combined with range query in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use Java API for executing scan and scroll query while combining it with range query but I am not getting any hits. I am not sure if it's a problem with my query or my data but below is my code:

```
String from = "1429192800000";
String to = "1429193100000";

QueryBuilder qb = rangeQuery("myField")
                 .gte(from)
                 .lte(to);

SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = client.prepareSearch(oldIndex)
                                     .setTypes("myType")
                                     .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                                     .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                                     .setQuery(qb)
                                     .setSize(100);
```

And here's my output:

```
{
   "_scroll_id" : my64BitScrolliD,
   "took" : 576,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
   "total" : 15,
   "successful" : 15,
   "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
   "total" : 0,
   "max_score" : 0.0,
   "hits" : [ ]
}
}
```

I have tried querying without using java api and still it doesn't return any hits. Here's my query:

```
  curl -XGET "http://localhost:9220/path/to/cluster/myIndex/myType/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m -d '{
     "size": 100,
     "query": {
        "range": {
          "myField": {
            "from": "1429192800000",
            "to": "1429193100000"
          }
        }
     }
  }'
```

And I get the same output as above. The field for which I have applied the range query holds an epoch timestamp and data exists between the specified range so there is no mistake with the query I suppose (I have tested it with just _search API and without using scan and scroll and it returned me hits!).

I would like to add that the scan and scroll query works fine if I don't combine range query with it! Since there is a really large amount of data, I want to get the results in batches by specifying the time range. Am I missing something basic here? Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: You are searching for "myField" instead of "reqDT".

Comment: I am sorry but I have just noticed it. I am searching for reqDT in my original system. I said it as "myField" just for a convenient format for people here to understand. Looks like I forgot to edit that part of the post here.